# Conversion of non numbered images to video with avconv

Tags: libav

I have many pictures which I want to make a movie from. The problem is that they don't follow a regular numeric order. They came from my smartphone camera, but some were captured in the same second, so their names are (for instance):

```
20180708_173141.jpg
20180708_173142.jpg
20180708_173142(0).jpg
20180708_173143.jpg
20180708_173145.jpg
```

I think I should do something like

```
avconv -r 10 -i 20180708_%06d.jpg test.avi
```

but I can't use `20180708_%06d.jpg`, because the third file above would be ignored. I tried using

```
avconv -r 10 -i 20180708*.jpg test.avi
```

but it says the second file on the list already exists, asking me if I want to overwrite it.

What should I do?

EDIT: I'm using Linux Debian 9 (Stretch) 64-bit.

Comment: In Windows, just make *a copy* (put originals somewhere safe) of all the files, pick them in the order you want, and in Explorer, select *Rename*. If you leave the original field blank, they'll be named (1).jpg, (2).jpg etc. See https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using Linux, edited the question to address this. Your solution will create files with a variable number of digits, (1), (2)... (9), (10), (11)... (99), (100), (101)... I think `avconv` will still have problems with that.

Comment: BTW, the Windows program IrfanView (which runs nicely in wine... it's one of the very few Windows executables I use on Linux) has batch renaming which can specify a fixed-length format such as 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg etc.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you. Yesterday I ended up creating a bash script. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a bash script to rename all files numerically ([from here](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/4572552)).

```
EII=1
for i in $(ls *.jpg)
do
  NEWNAME=IMG_`printf "%3d" $EII`.JPG
  mv $i $NEWNAME
  EII=`expr $EII + 1`
done
```

Then I could apply

```
avconv -r 10 -i IMG_%3d.jpg test.avi
```

Comment: Still one question remains: if I needed to change the position of some images, let's say, move the 030 to between 040 and 041, I could rename it to 040a, but then how would `avconv` treat this? Or should I rename all files between 030 and 040, so that the moved image could fit into place? I really can't use wildcards like * ?